# How to use a string or a substring of the string in a path to file

Tags: java, file

I am writing a program to get stored proc's from xml files. I have the program running on one file. But i need to run it on multiple files. The problem is I find the correct xml files in a large directory.

For example, the path could either be

C:\DevStore\com\dev\Store\sql\store.xml

or

C:\Store\com\dev\DevStore\sql\store.xml

so on....

So, for the above example i can either have DevStore or store, in three possible places.

How can i make the file path use either DevStore or any substring of DevStore in these three place?

I am sorry if the question is unclear, I wasn't sure how to word it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what code have you tried for

Comment: You can define a start point and traverse the folders recursively, searching for xml files.

Comment: You would need to look for files in those locations. There's no magic thing that will do this for you.

Comment: You must show your code. In general you will have to work with some kind of configuration parameters.

Comment: Hi, there are other xml files in these folders that I don't need to scan. I one need to scan the ones in this specific path and that name. (i.e. Either DevStore.xml or Store.xml)

Comment: `new File(filepath).exists()` for both locations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that you can start your work.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void traverseAndProcess( File startDir ) {
        for ( File f : startDir.listFiles() ) {
            // this file is a directory?
            if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                // yes, it is, so we need to go inside this directory
                // calling the method again
                traverseAndProcess( f );
            } else {
                // no, it is not a directory
                // verifies if the file name finishes with ".xml"
                if ( f.getName().lastIndexOf( ".xml" ) != -1 ) {
                    // it is a xml (just verifying the extension)
                    // so, process this file!
                    process( f );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void process( File f ) {
        // here you will process the xml
        System.out.println( "Processing " + f + " file..." );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // processing the current directory... change it
        traverseAndProcess( new File( "./" ) );
    }

}
```

My class design is not the best one, but as I said, you can start by the code above.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use wildcards in `File` paths, but this "wheel" has already been invented...

Use [Apache commons-io library](http://commons.apache.org/io/)'s [`FileUtils.listFiles()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#listFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method, which will recursively get all matching files from a directory, in this case `C:\` (ie `new File("/")`.

You'll have to do some filtering, and running it will illustrate why you shouldn't store projects directly under your root drive - always put them under `C:\Projects` or similar, then you won't have to scan though a gazillion windows files when looking for certain project files.